# MySQL.Data DateTime.Kind being different between SQL DATETIME and TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, .net-core, mysql-connector

So I updated to `MySql.Data 8.0.13` and I noticed that my `TIMESTAMP` fields come as `DateTimeKind.Local` and the `DATETIME` fields are read as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`

I thought that "Timestamp" would be a great semantic type to represent a "CreatedTime" field, so I went with it.

The thing is, I usually write these dates "manually" in the insert queries, they're generated by the application, in UTC, to make sure that local time and their crazy timezones/daylight savings won't break anything. I don't use on-update or on-insert on them. And now I'm getting problems with the application's JSON serializer converting an already UTC time to UTC again, which causes a wrong offset time.

So my question:

Is there a way to enforce MySQL.Data to "Consider those dates/timestamps as being UTC"? Or is it best for me to discontinue the usage of `TIMESTAMP` and adhere to `DATETIME` instead?
Or should I pull a crazy gimmick like this?

```
if(databaseValue is DateTime dt) {
     databaseValue = new DateTime(dt.Ticks, DateTimeKind.UTC);
}
```

Which would be the preferable way to solve this problem?

Comment: Which way most effectively satisfies your specific requirements?

Comment: Ok i did some research and it seems mysql connector .net doesnt support any timezone option in the Connection String, to make it I'd have to issue SET on every connection I opened and make obnoxious checks, so I'll have to go with my convictions and force the microorm to ignore the `DateTimeKind` specified by the dbms and consider it as always having been UTC. "If this date isn't UTC then it was saved wrong", I'm sure many could see heresy in what I'm going to do, but life is easier in UTC.

Comment: I am seriously annoyed by this though, I really wish and hope for an elegant and adequate alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an alternative library [MySqlConnector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/) which has a `DateTimeKind` option you can specify in the [connection string](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/connection-options/#other-options):

> The DateTimeKind used when MySqlDataReader returns a DateTime. If set
>   to Utc or Local, a MySqlException will be thrown if a DateTime command
>   parameter has a Kind of Local or Utc, respectively.

Comment: I've been fiddling with this and it seems fairly robust and adequate, thanks.